# Name for the set of limit points of $X$ not in $X$

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Title is straightforward, I'm wondering if there is a name for for the set of limit points of $X$ not in $X$. So $Cl(X)\setminus X$. I had never encounter this specific construction, until I read the equivalent definitions for sequential spaces in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), see 3. and 4..

Related to this, I wonder if you know another place where this construction appears.

Comment: When $X$ is open, this set coincides with the boundary $\partial X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\overline{X}\setminus X$ is called by some authors (though it's rare, so should always be explained/defined) **frontier** of $X$, $\operatorname{Fr}(X)$. Others use that name and notation for the usual boundary $\overline{X}\setminus \operatorname{int}(X)$ of $X$ (usually denoted by $\partial X$; these two sets of course coincide if $\operatorname{int}(X)=X$ i.e. when $X$ is open, and as such it's used in older complex analysis texts (where functions are usually defined on domains, or Gebiete, i.e. open connected subsets of $\Bbb C$).